# How do I get an existing app to use the new permissions dialog?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

How do I get an existing app to use the new permissions dialog? 
I am using oAuth 2.0, which sends the visitor to facebook.com/oauth/authorize.

If I try and add extended permissions like "user_actions.music" I get this error: Error Message: invalid permissions: user_actions.music.

Am I missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** It seems that you need to use the old notation: `perms` instead of `scope`!

Comment: Umm, there is a permission called that. You can find more details on the official documentation:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/authentication/read/

Comment: Sorry about that, I missed that document! Please read the update.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't think that is working though. If I hit this URL, it doesn't prompt me to grant my app any additional permissions:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=12345&perms=user_actions.music,friends_actions.music&redirect_uri=http://www.foo.com/FBAppAuth.aspx?foo=bar

Comment: True, the auth dialog is now showing but nothing in there. To be honest I'm not sure if this is a bug or not, also I'm not sure if using `perms` is intended! I recommend you create a ticker on the bug tracker and post a link back here?